# How can I get a collection of the assemblies in my .NET solution?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, powershell

For a .NET solution, is there a way to get all the .dll files for each project in the solution? For example, if I make an empty .NET solution (this is Visual Studio 2010 btw), and add 3 projects called "a", "b" and "c", and build each, providing me with dll's a.dll, b.dll, and c.dll, is there any code sample in either C# or Powershell which could give me a collection of of these .dlls (but not any other .dlls like 3rd party libraries used)?

Thanks

Comment: What is the point of this?  Use Fuslogvw.exe.

Comment: Would you be OK getting them by executing a build and parsing the output? That would narrow it down to a specific configuration/platform and you can easily parse the log output for build outputs rather than parsing the conditions on the project files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way (without writing a VS addin) would be parsing the project file. The project file (which is in XML format) will have an element called ProjectReference (regular references are in another element, called `Reference`):

```
<Project ...>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\path\YourProject.csproj">
      ...
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

You could simply parse this, with any XML API you have in your toolset and get the name of the dll by using the name of the project (the `Include` attribute). This works of course only if your project has the same name as the dll. If it hasn't, you could open the `csproj` file and find the element `<AssemblyName>`

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to implement a 100% robust solution for this scenario.  Project files, while usually simple, can get very complex as people take advantage of the flexibility of MSBuild.  It's possible for instance for the same project to build assemblies with very different names given specific build settings.  This makes it very difficult to pick out the assembly name without understanding the overall build context.

However for the most straight forward cases the following powershell script will do the trick.  Make sure that it's run in the same directory as the specified solution file.

```
gc SomeProject.sln |
    ? { $_ -match "^Project" } |
    % { ($_.Split(","))[1].Trim().Trim('"') } |
    ? { $_ -match ".*proj" } |
    % { $x = [xml](gc $_); $x.Project.PropertyGroup[0].AssemblyName } |
    % { $_ + ".dll" }
```

Comment: Yeah, the two things you need are the `OutputPath` and the `AssemblyName` from each project.  But even in the simplest case, the output path changes based on the Configuration and Platform that are selected (eg: Debug vs Release).

Answer (score 0):

what about using the [EnvDTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte%28VS.80%29.aspx) namespace? A related example is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548026/get-referenced-projects-path-in-t4-template).