# Adding assembly in controller.cs.tt in VS 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, t4

I need to add my project dll file to my controller.cs.tt T4 template file. 
The following declaration works.

```
<#@ assembly name="C:\Users\noornayeem\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\bin\WebApplication2.dll" #>
```

However, I tried with

```
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)WebApplication2\bin\WebApplication2.dll" #>
```

The above one doesn't work. It shows `Compiling transformation: Metadata file $(SolutionDir) could not be found`. I tried `$(ProjectDir)`. It doesn't work either. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548026/get-referenced-projects-path-in-t4-template

Comment: that link is not helpful for my case

Comment: Care to explain why not? MSBuild macros like `$(SolutionDir)` don't work in T4, so you'll have to find a workaround.

Comment: It basically shows how to get a file path. But I want to know how to add an assembly directive.

Comment: No you don't, your first code block already shows that. That works. It's the $(SolutionDir) that doesn't, how to make that work is explained in the link in my first comment.

Comment: Thank you so much for the link. I would really appreciate if you summarize the solution. It would be helpful if you can provide some code sample.

Comment: The second answer shows how to get access to the Visual Studio Project system to get access to the Solution object. Form there it should be easy to grab the location: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3596269/736079

Comment: I saw that answer. But how can I add the dll file name to my assembly directive?

Answer (score 0):

This does work in VS2013:

```
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)\projectFolder\bin\debug\assembly.dll" #>
```

Try editing `$(SolutionDir)WebApplication2` and include `\` after  `$(SolutionDir)`.